# Multiple Tomcat Instances

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java, load-balancing

I have One Staic IP on one Server which is publically accessible over the Internet. I am running an Apache WebServer on that Server.

How can I make -  3 Web Applications (On Tomcat) running on 3 different intranet PC's - available over the Internet - using the one Publically accessible IP that I have?.

It should be noted that the Static-IP Server Machine can has two network adapters and can definitely access the intranet PC's too.

Please advise the best method to solve this problem. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

My tomcat virtual hosts settings:

first enable mod_jk for apache:

a2enmod mod_jk

then restart apache

cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tomcat:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/mydomain1.com
 ServerName mydomain1.com
 JkMount /* mydomain1
 ErrorLog /usr/share/tomcat5.5/logs/mydomain1.com-error_log
 CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /usr/share/tomcat5.5/logs/mydomain1.com-access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/mydomain2.com
 ServerName mydomain2.com
 JkMount /* mydomain2
 ErrorLog /usr/share/tomcat5.5/logs/mydomain2.com-error_log
 CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /usr/share/tomcat5.5/logs/mydomain2.com-access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

cat /etc/apache2/workers.properties

```
workers.tomcat_home=/usr/share/tomcat5.5/
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
ps=/
worker.list=mydomain1, mydomain2

worker.lic.type=ajp13
worker.lic.host=mydomain1.com
worker.lic.port=8009
worker.lic.lbfactor=1

worker.wideok.type=ajp13
worker.wideok.host=mydomain2.com
worker.wideok.port=8009
worker.wideok.lbfactor=1
```

cat /usr/share/tomcat5.5/conf/server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Environment name="simpleValue" type="java.lang.Integer" value="30"/>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
        description="User database that can be updated and saved"
        factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
        pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150000" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="3600000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />


    <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" SSLEnabled="true"
               keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/somedomain.com/ROOT/WEB-INF/ssl/sms_ssl.key" keystorePass="changeit"
            sslProtocol="SSL" />

 <Connector port="8009" 
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
 <Listener className="org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig"
    modJk="/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so"
    workersConfig="/etc/apache2/workers.properties"/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

 <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
 </Host>

 <Host name="mydomain1.com"
    appBase="/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/mydomain1.com"
    unpackWARs="true"
    autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false"
    xmlNamespaceAware="false">
 </Host>

 <Host name="mydomain2.com"
    appBase="/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/mydomain2.com"
    unpackWARs="true"
    autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false"
    xmlNamespaceAware="false">
 </Host>

</Engine></Service></Server>
```

and dir structure for /usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps

```
/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/
                             ROOT/WEB-INF
                             ROOT/index.jsp

/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/mydomain1.com/
                                          ROOT/WEB-INF
                                          ROOT/index.jsp

/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/mydomain2.com/
                                          ROOT/WEB-INF
                                          ROOT/index.jsp
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use mod_jk or mod_proxy to connect Apache httpd and Tomcat, this is very easy to do.

First, you assign a path for each Tomcat, like

```
  http://example.com/app1
  http://example.com/app2
```

Use mod_jk as example, you need to setup workers for each Tomcat (worker1, worker2) and just redirect the request to the corresponding worker like this,

```
  JkMount  /app1/* worker1
  JkMount  /app2/* worker1
```

If you don't want to assign path for some reason, you need to get multiple domain names, one for each Tomcat and use mod_rewrite to inject the path internally based on `HTTP_HOST` header value.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html)